# Azure Web App, changes not reflected after publishing one file

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-webapps

Blazor Server App
made some changes to the navigation menu, if run locally I can see the changes, and I published successfully `NavMenu.razor` (right click on the file and I selected 'Publish')from Visual Studio. The changes are not reflected on the actual site and I stopped and started the app multiple times. I have added the following settings

```cs
WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 0
WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = Never
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 0
```

but to no avail.

UPDATE:
According to ChatGPT

*When you make changes to a Razor component in your Blazor Server application, you need to recompile and redeploy the entire application for the changes to take effect.
....
To deploy the modified Razor component, you should follow the regular deployment process for your Blazor Server application, which involves publishing the entire application, including the server-side code and components.*

Is this correct?

Comment: How did you deploy or publish the app is it from VS or VS code

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention it in the initial post, from VS

Answer (score 0):

"Razor files with a .cshtml extension are compiled at both build and publish time using the Razor SDK."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

What may be happening is that when you publish a single file it is not being used, since the app continues to use the version of the file compiled into the dll.

Comment: I do not know if it makes a difference, but I do not have any .cshtml extension only `NavMenu.razor` and `NavMenu.razor.css`